# How can I display network topology and status in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display network equipment (i.e computers, switch and etc with its connections and bit rate) in a local network.

For a simple example something like this(actually problem may has more devices and connections):

```
Computer A ----\ 3kb/sec    Computer C
                \          /
                 Switch --/ 4kb/sec
                 /
Computer B -----/ 1kb/sec
```

I have device icon, status of links and value of bit rates but I do not know how to display and manage these in a react project *effectively*. In the first try I draw each device and link in HTML `<svg>` tag statically(i.e plot each one in a specific coordinate...).

```js
import React from 'react';

const renderInput = (line, idx) => {
 let l = line.points.reduce(
  (prev, next) =>
   (prev.x && prev.y ? 'M' + prev.x + ',' + prev.y : prev) + ' L' + next.x + ',' + next.y
 );

 return [
  <text
   key={'input-caption'}
   x={line.points[0].x + 3}
   y={line.points[0].y - 3}
   fill={line.caption.fill}
   style={line.caption.style}
  >
   {line.caption.text}
  </text>,
  <defs key={`arrow-${idx}`}>
   <marker id="markerArrow" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refX="3" refY="6" orient="auto">
    <path d="M2,4 L2,8 L5,6 L2,4" style={{ fill: '#2dc408' }} />
   </marker>
  </defs>,
  <path
   key={`line-${idx}`}
   d={l}
   style={{
    stroke: '#2dc408',
    strokeWidth: '2px',
    fill: 'none',
    // markerStart: "url(#markerCircle)",
    markerEnd: 'url(#markerArrow)'
   }}
  />
 ];
};

const renderInputs = inputs => {
 const result = inputs.map((line, idx) => renderInput(line, idx));
 return result;
};

const Asset = ({ asset, inputs }) => {
 const renderedInputs = renderInputs(inputs);

 return [
  renderedInputs,
  <image
   key={'logo-img'}
   href={asset.icon}
   x={asset.logo.location.x}
   y={asset.logo.location.y}
   height={asset.logo.size.height}
   width={asset.logo.size.width}
  />,
  <text
   key={'asset-name'}
   x={asset.caption.location.x}
   y={asset.caption.location.y}
   fill={asset.caption.fill}
   style={asset.caption.style}
  >
   {asset.caption.text}
  </text>
 ];
};

export default Asset;
```

As you can see in the above code I get device location and name in the `asset` props and its links in the `input` props to plot it in the screen.

This approach has following problems.

1. result is not responsive
2. it is not flexible(i.e, user could not zoom/unzoom or expand/de-expand network topology to get desired view)
3. managing devices and links is tedious work

Comment: What have your tried, where is your code? I'll vote to close this, as you basically ask us finding a solution for you.

Comment: @eisbehr Current code includes multiple files to show devices and connection between them(all of them goes on a `svg` tag and locations are static). Since this approach is not desired and is tedious I do not put its code here. I think there must be component to do that in a elegant way. So I explained the problem and need your recommendations...

Comment: Yes, but these question are _off topic_ by the rules of SO. Please take a look on point `4.` of the list here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @eisbehr I modified the question statement.

Comment: This looks interesting: https://react-topology.now.sh/ 
Might help!

Comment: @bamse Thanks for your response. I saw it, it is very cool and flexible but what I want to show as net-topology is something like [this](https://live.yworks.com/demos/view/graphviewer/index.html) with colored links and numbers on its edges...

Comment: I think you would need to mod something by your own if you have this special wishes. There are enough examples available, like: https://live.yworks.com/demos/complete/networkmonitoring/index.html and https://live.yworks.com/demos/analysis/networkflows/index.html